# How to make a option in a macro in word selected by default?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following macro in word 2010. I would like to make value 1 (Copenhagen) preselected when I run the macro - So it put my content control drop down list in the document with Copenhagen as preselected.

How do I do thiS ?:

```
Sub Cities()
'
' Cities Macro
'
'
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlDropdownList)
Selection.ParentContentControl.Title = "Cities"
Selection.ParentContentControl.LockContentControl = False
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Copenhagen", Value:="1"
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="New York", Value:="2"
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="London", Value:="3"
Selection.ParentContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Paris", Value:="4"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

/ Anders H.

Answer (score 0):

Did you study [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836949.aspx)? This is for Word 2013 but it is more detailed than the 2010 version of this page.

```
Sub Cities()
    '
    ' Cities Macro
    '
    '
    Dim objCC As ContentControl
    Dim objCE As ContentControlListEntry

    Set objCC = Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
    With objCC
        .Title = "Cities"
        .LockContentControl = False
        '.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Copenhagen", Value:="1"
        Set objCE = .DropdownListEntries.Add("Copenhagen", "1")
        objCE.Select
        'or
        '.DropdownListEntries.Add("Copenhagen", "1").Select

        .DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="New York", Value:="2"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="London", Value:="3"
        .DropdownListEntries.Add Text:="Paris", Value:="4"
    End With
    'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    'Selection is no longer in the document range
End Sub
```

This uses the `Select` method to select Copenhagen. It does mean, however, that the Selection is no longer in the document-range. You can use something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Characters(1).Select
```

(or a million other ways..) to move the cursor back into the document-range, leaving Copenhagen selected.

Comment: What if I would put text around it in the same macro?

Fx:
"I have been to <Copenhagen> on the 2th of July 2013."

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry for being bad at VBA... I want the macro to have som text then a ContentControlDropdownList then som text again... FX: "I have been to <Copenhagen> on the 2th of July 2013."

Comment: You would just insert the first text into the document, then the control, then the second text. I still don't understand how this relates to your question.

Comment: If I make the following macro:
`Sub Cities

Selection.TypeText Text:="I been to "
<your surgestion>
Selection.TypeText Text:=" on the 2th of July 2013."
End Sub`
It comes back with a error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Cities()
'
' Cities Macro
'
'

Selection.TypeText Text:='I learned English with Google translate in "
Dim oldRange as Range
Set oldRange = Selection ' I didn't try this but it should work

Dim objCC As ContentControl

Set objCC = Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlDropdownList)
With objCC
    .Title = "Cities"
    .LockContentControl = False
    .DropdownListEntries.Add("Copenhagen", "1").Select
    .DropdownListEntries.Add("New York",   "2")
    .DropdownListEntries.Add("London",     "3")
    .DropdownListEntries.Add("Paris",      "4")
End With
Set Selection = oldRange ' didn't try this but should work. We should be back in the document
' or try ActiveDocument.Characters(1).Select followed by a move to the end of the doc.
' or put in a placeholder (text like "zzzxxxzzz"  and then find it) or a bookmark and then use it.
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 ' didn't try this but should work. If it "falls" back into the content control then try the following:
Selection.TypeText Text:=" on the 2nd of July, 2013."
' if there is an error mark out the last line and check where the selection ends up after MoveRight.
```

End Sub